# Factorize $z^6 + 1$, and deduce $\cos{3x} = \cos{x}(2\cos{x}+\sqrt{3})(2\cos{x}-\sqrt{3})$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

> Factorise $z^6 + 1$ into real quadratic factors.
>
> Hence, deduce that $\cos{3x} = \cos{x}(2\cos{x}+\sqrt{3})(2\cos{x}-\sqrt{3})$

I factorised $z^6+1$ into $(z^2+1)(z^4-z^2+1)$, then tried using De Moivre to get complex roots, but I ended up nowhere.

Comment: Your second factor is a quadratic in $z^2$, factorize it as usual, probably using polar form for the roots, and see what happens.

Comment: I see they are equivalent to the de moivre complex roots, but I dont know how to turn it into the required deduction

Comment: Do you mean using De Moivre's formula to obtain solutions for $z^6=-1$? Please, show us your attempt; "ended up nowhere" tells nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$z^6+1$$
$$=(z^2+1)(z^2+\sqrt 3z+1)(z^2-\sqrt 3z+1)$$
$$=(z^4+z^2)(z+\sqrt 3+1/z)(z-\sqrt 3+1/z)$$
Divide by $z^3$:
$$z^3+z^{-3}=(z+1/z)(z+\sqrt 3+1/z)(z-\sqrt 3+1/z)$$
Let $z=e^{ix}$, then $z+1/z=2\cos x$ and $z^3+z^{-3}=2\cos 3x$.
$$2\cos 3x=2\cos x(2\cos x+\sqrt 3)(2\cos x-\sqrt 3)$$
$$\cos 3x=\cos x(2\cos x+\sqrt 3)(2\cos x-\sqrt 3)$$